# KOTLIN - How to represent message length as 2 binary bytes

Tags: android, kotlin, binary, byte, ascii

I am facing a problem while building an integration between ECR (electronic cash register) and an android POS. I'm working on the android POS and i want to calculate the message size and add it in "2 bytes, binary".

I have this block of code to calculate and generate the complete message

```
fun  generateMessage(message: String): String {
    
            return buildString {
                append(Constants.DIRECTION)
                append(AppData.getProtocolVariant())
                append(AppData.getProtocolVersion())
                append(message)
    
                val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2)
                buffer.putShort(message.length.toShort())
                insert(0, buffer.array().decodeToString())
            }
        }
```

But this code only works for really small messages, because in the logs i can see that for larger messages this code adds 3 digits and communication fails.
The complete message is in the form of <MSG SIZE(2 bytes, binary)><DIRECTION INDICATOR(3 bytes, ascii)><PROTOCOL VARIANT(2 bytes, ascii)><PROTOCOL VERSION(2 bytes, ascii)><Actual messsage (MSG SIZE-7)>

When I send a simple message "E/000" (hex dump 45 2f 30 30 30) the code works and the ECR accepts it and in the logs i see "��POS0110E/000" when i have a bigger message i see something like this "���POS0110R/S852484/RDLF****16/T93/M0/C00/DMastercard:00:0000********1234:200:200:0:0:0:1:80*****3:2:133030119089:193439:497853:20230926115814:0"

which has 3 digits for the message size and it fails.

So how can i create this message and follow the protocol <MSG SIZE(2 bytes, binary)>?

```
override fun sendMessage(message: String) { 
      val finalMessage = Utils.generateMessage(message) 
      server.sendMessage(finalMessage.encodeToByteArray()) }
```

`

changed the code to

```
 fun sendMessage(bytes: ByteArray) { 
   coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { 
    val outputStream = socket?.getOutputStream() 
    outputStream?.write(bytes) 
    outputStream?.flush() 
  } 
}`
```

and still is not accepted

example from the guide [image]

Comment: What are the length of the messages? Tell us the two and three leading values in hexadecimal notation as then we know the length. You only need three bytes for lengths bigger then 16575 or 34784 so tell.

Comment: Further you cannot pack -two- byte values in a string variable. You have to sent them as bytes. Not as strings.

Comment: here's an example that the ECR sends and it is correct: 00 17 45 43 52 30 32 31 30 58 2F 48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 66 72 6F 6D 20 45 43 52 which in utf 8 is ..ECR0210X/Hello from ECR . 00 17 here is the message size

Comment: But is the data stored as binary or as hex? If binary, then `String` can't hold binary data. It is for textual data. You have to use `ByteArray` or something similar - depending on how do you write/read the data.

Comment: Give an example where there are three leading bytes. And tell the size in decimal too. You did not even react in the sizes i spoke of.

Comment: this is how i send the message fun sendMessage(message: String) {
        coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val writer = socket?.getOutputStream()?.writer()
            writer?.write(message)
            writer?.flush()
        }
    } if this helps

Comment: Thats wrong as you cannot send bytes with strings. Send/write the bytes directly.

Comment: but the guide says <MSG SIZE(2 bytes, binary)><DIRECTION INDICATOR(3 bytes, ascii)><PROTOCOL VARIANT(2 bytes, ascii)><PROTOCOL VERSION(2 bytes, ascii)><Actual messsage (MSG SIZE-7)>

Comment: example of 3 digit ���POS0110R/S262681/RDLF77000016/T94/M0/C00/DMastercard:00:0000********1234:200:200:0:0:0:1:80011693:2:133030119089:024891:896734:20230926125159:0

Comment: Post the hexadecimal values of the three bytes example. And tell the length in decimal too.

Comment: 52 2f 53 32 36 32 36 38 31 2f 52 44 4c 46 37 37 30 30 30 30 31 36 2f 54 39 34 2f 4d 30 2f 43 30 30 2f 44 4d 61 73 74 65 72 63 61 72 64 3a 30 30 3a 30 30 30 30 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 31 32 33 34 3a 32 30 30 3a 32 30 30 3a 30 3a 30 3a 30 3a  31 3a 38 30 30 31 31 36 39 33 3a 32 3a 31 33 33 30 33 30 31 31 39 30 38 39 3a 30 32 34 38 39 31 3a 38 39 36 37 33 34 3a 32 30 32 33 30 39 32 36 31 32 35 31 35 39 3a 30 hex dump of above message

Comment: You must write bytes to the OutputStream. Your approach is wrong. Instead of trying to but the binary bytes into a String along with the rest of your data, you need to convert your String data into bytes and create a byte array containing your message. You then write these bytes to the OutputStream.

Comment: let me try this and i ll come back

Comment: @blackapps 00 ef bf  - for decimal 143 my code adds a 00

Comment: Please update the question with your latest code.

Comment: added code and example

Comment: After the update you do pretty much the same - you try to create a `String` with a binary header. You can't do that. Strings can't hold binary data. `generateMessage()` should return `ByteArray` and you should never try to write the size header to any string.

Comment: do you think the message size and the actual messages are 2 different actions? Should i send them to the ECR in separate?

Comment: No, message size and actual message are all part of the same thing. You should send a byte stream to ECR including message size and the data

Comment: 143 decimal is 8F hexadecimal. So you should sent bytes 00 and 8F then. You have the wrong approach now by converting three decimal digits. If the length were 12345  in your approach you would sent five bytes where two were enough. As 12345 decimal is 3039 in hexadecimal notation hence bytes 30 and 39.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write bytes to the `OutputStream`, not a `String`. You should change your `generateMessage()` method to return a `ByteArray` instead of a `String`, like this:

```
fun generateMessage(message: String): ByteArray {
    val x = buildString {
        append(Constants.DIRECTION)
        append(AppData.getProtocolVariant())
        append(AppData.getProtocolVersion())
        append(message)
    }
    // Create byte array containing 2-byte message length (binary) followed
    //  by the actual message
    val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2 + x.length)
    buffer.putShort(x.length.toShort())
    buffer.put(x.getBytes())
    return buffer
}
```

Also, please note that the message length (according to the example from the guide you pasted) is the length of the entire message (including the header: direction, protocol version, etc.). In your code you only used the length of the actual message (not including the header data).

Comment: cant stress enough of how much i THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, we can't use strings to construct binary messages. Strings are for texts and they can't hold binary data correctly. To process binary data we have to use `ByteArray` or other similar buffer.

I may not be able to replicate your exact case, but it should be something along lines:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
fun main() {
    val msg = generateMessage("Hello world!")
    println(msg.decodeToString()) // ??POS0110Hello world!
    println(msg.toHexString()) // 0013504f533031313048656c6c6f20776f726c6421
}

fun generateMessage(message: String): ByteArray {
    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val out = DataOutputStream(baos)

    val data = message.toByteArray(Charsets.US_ASCII)
    out.writeShort(data.size + 7)
    out.write(Constants.DIRECTION)
    out.write(AppData.getProtocolVariant())
    out.write(AppData.getProtocolVersion())
    out.write(data)

    return baos.toByteArray()
}

object Constants {
    val DIRECTION = "POS".toByteArray(Charsets.US_ASCII)
}

object AppData {
    fun getProtocolVariant() = "01".toByteArray(Charsets.US_ASCII)
    fun getProtocolVersion() = "10".toByteArray(Charsets.US_ASCII)
}
```

Size header is `0013` in hex, so 19. This is correct, as `POS0110Hello world!` is 19 bytes.

Please note we use big endian here. That matches the format provided in the example image.

If we like hardcode Kotlin programming, we could alternatively use this:

```kotlin
fun generateMessage(message: String) = ByteArrayOutputStream().also {
    with (DataOutputStream(it)) {
        val data = message.toByteArray(Charsets.US_ASCII)
        writeShort(data.size + 7)
        write(Constants.DIRECTION)
        write(AppData.getProtocolVariant())
        write(AppData.getProtocolVersion())
        write(data)
    }
}.toByteArray()
```

Comment: thanks a lot guys, you teach me something today